# ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: syntax: "()" is not a valid function argument name

Tags: tensorflow, julia

While trying to load TensorFlow in Julia, I gets the error

> ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: syntax: "()" is not a valid function argument name

I could not get the solution. I am using Ubuntu and Julia version 0.6.0
The problems:

```
julia> using TensorFlow
INFO: Precompiling module TensorFlow.
WARNING: Loading a new version of TensorFlow.jl for the first time. This initial load can take around 5 minutes as code is precompiled; subsequent usage will only take a few seconds.
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: syntax: "()" is not a valid function argument name
Stacktrace:
 [1] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:569
 [2] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [3] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:569
 [4] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [5] anonymous at ./<missing>:2
while loading /home/spg/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/ops.jl, in expression starting on line 119
while loading /home/spg/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/TensorFlow.jl, in expression starting on line 184
ERROR: Failed to precompile TensorFlow to /home/spg/.julia/lib/v0.6/TensorFlow.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] compilecache(::String) at ./loading.jl:703
 [2] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:490
 [3] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:398
```

Comment: I remove the tensorflow and re-installed again and got the same error:

Answer (score 0):

Following this [link](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/issues/339), run `Pkg.update()`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.